# Unable to set current timestamp as default

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default

I am trying to set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value for my `DATE` type in phpmyadmin. I first tried to set `DATE` type, and then to `DATETIME` type, but i'm getting this error:

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'registered_at'
```

So, how can I set current timestamp as default value ?

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: Pls also share the version of the mysql server as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Nemus phpmyadmin generates and executes an sql statement. Copy that sql statement into the question.

Comment: If you don't post your code, we can't help you. We can't tell what might be a typo or something else. We can't solve problems with code we can't see. The definition of your column is also relevant. See [ask].

Comment: @KenWhite OP's probably clicking around in the phpMyAdmin UI. While there's SQL behind-the-scenes, I don't remember if the webapp presents it in this case.

Comment: @KenWhite I am using phpMyAdmin UI, there is no sql statements....

Comment: @ceejayoz: I have no idea what the poster is doing, because the poster didn't include that information in the post. The information about the column datatype is not included either. We're supposed to use our psychic abilities here, I guess. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite The post does say "for my DATE type in phpmyadmin".

Comment: @ceejayoz: I've lost count of how many questions I've seen here that say *I'm trying to do something with my date column* only to find out it was defined as VARCHAR.

Comment: @ceejayoz and then writes datetime as well. So, we need to see the code.

Comment: Like I said, OP probably doesn't have code - they just clicked some boxes in the UI. Reasonably sure @BillKarwin's answer is correct - you can't use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on a `DATE` column (or `VARCHAR`, for that matter).

Comment: I could only include screenshot of phpMyAdmin UI that i am clicking on it. There is NO CODE.

Comment: @Nemus use the preview sql button in phpmyadmin to see the sql statement that will be run...

Comment: @Shadow I really can't see somethnig like "preview sql button" .... i am trying to create table with phpmyadmin, clicking on ui, and having trouble to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default on DATE type......anyway, it doesn't matter, answer bellow did fix my problem, I changed to TIMESTAMP data type ..... i'm gonna delete this question, because i'm not sure don't you really understand my question, or you're just trolling me ?!

Comment: @Nemus it would not hurt if you actually knew the gui you actually use. As Ken said, as long as there is no code, it is difficult to know what you are doing. I also specifically asked you to share the version of your mysql about 45 mins ago, which you conveniently ignored. In the light of the answer beliw, why do you think I asked the question? So, we are not trolling you, you just asked a question in a really bad way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use MySQL Server 5.6.5 or later to do this. You also need to use the TIMESTAMP or DATETIME data types. It won't work with DATE.

The example in the manual shows both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you have an earlier version of MySQL Server, you need to use the TIMESTAMP data type only. It won't work with DATETIME.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html for more information.